# Moving Thunderbird message pane to middle

Tags: linux, ubuntu, thunderbird

I'm using Thunderbird 3.1 with "vertical view", but I'd like to have the message pane as middle pane, is it possible?
I tried following [this guide](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Window_layout_-_Thunderbird) and adding a userChrome.css inside $HOME/.thunderbird/$profile/chrome with this content:

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

#messagesBox {-moz-box-direction: reverse;}
```

but nothing changes.. Am I missing something?

(Xubuntu 9.04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace #messagesBox with #threadPaneBox. I found this solution at http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=623255 and it works with Ubuntu 10.10 and Thunderbird 7.0.1.

Comment: It works with 10.04 too :) Thanks!